# How to constantly show line number when navigating in nano?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, editors, nano

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to show the line numbers in nano editor when navigating up and and down within the file.

I have seen in multiple posts about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but this doesn't automatically refresh the line number while navigating.

I remember that in the past I have used such shortcut in Linux terminal and if I recall it was for nano. I also think that it worked out of the box, I didn't have to change any parameters like this article shows: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73444/how-to-show-line-numbering-in-nano-when-opening-a-file

Is there any shortcut to do this?
I have Ubuntu 16.04 and GNU nano 2.5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable and disable the lines number for each individual line instead through:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>  + <kbd>#</kbd>

see the help (Open `nano` then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> ):

```
M-#             Line numbering enable/disable
```

Note that you can also enable line-numbering from the command-line too, using the argument `-l`, for example:

```
$ nano -l somefile.txt
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this numbers each individual line, rather than constantly displaying the position at the bottom of the screen (as done temporarily by Ctrl+C).

Answer (score 1):

Nano's default options are set in the config file /etc/nanorc so you can configure it to show line numbers by default on all files by uncommenting the "# set linenumbers" option, or run this from your terminal:

```
sed -i 's/# set linenumbers/set linenumbers/g' /etc/nanorc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-l` or `--linenumbers` flags. So,

```
nano -l yourfile.txt
```

To make it permanent, uncomment `set linenumbers` in `/home/<username>/.nanorc` or `/etc/nanorc`